# Not able to switch to an iFrame which is within a <section> tag

Tags: selenium, iframe

I am getting *NoSuchFrame* exception when trying to switch to an iFrame which is wrapped up in a `<section>` tag. Could somebody help me in this please?

I am trying to switch to iFrame for my selenium test. I have used `driver.switchTo()` method to switch to iFrame.

The `<section>` HTML:

```
<section id="modal-root">
 <div class="modal-wrapper">
   <div id="#####" class="modal-container modal-enter-done">
     <div class="modal ####" role="dialog">
    <button type="button" aria-label="Close Modal" class="button-icon 
        modal-close">
    <span class="icon icon-x">
    <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" 
         role="presentation">
      <path d="M8.41421 7L13.7071 12.2929C14.0976 12.6834 14.0976 13.3166 
           13.7071 13.7071C13.3166 14.0976 12.6834 14.0976 12.2929 13.7071L7 
           8.41421L1.70711 13.7071C1.31658 14.0976 0.683418 14.0976 0.292893
       13.7071C-0.0976311 13.3166 -0.0976311 12.6834 0.292893 
           12.2929L5.58579 7L0.292893 1.70711C-0.0976311 1.31658 
      -0.0976311 0.683418 0.292893 0.292893C0.683418 -0.0976311 1.31658 
          -0.0976311 1.70711 0.292893L7 5.58579L12.2929 0.292893C12.6834 
          -0.0976311 13.3166 -0.0976311 13.7071 0.292893C14.0976 0.683418 
           14.0976 1.31658 13.7071 1.70711L8.41421 7Z" transform="translate(5 
           5)" fill="black">
      </path>
    </svg>
      </span>
    </button>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="#####">
    <iframe title="######" id="#####" name="#####"src="######">
    </iframe>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-overlay">
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

I am trying to switch to the iFrame in my test. I am running the following snippet:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get(url);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.switchTo().frame(iFrame_id);
```

I am getting below exception:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: No frame element found by
>   name or id iFrame_id

I am not sure if I will be able to switch to iFrame directly, as it is wrapped up in a `<section>` tag.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Search the page source for "frame" and see if there are multiple frames or iframes.  The one you want might be nested.

Comment: If it is just one iframe then just use the index to switch. The frame id could be dynamic.  driver.switchTo().frame(0);

Comment: @Sureshmani While using index 0 will work for now in that case, it would be best to see if it has an ID or a name and use that. In the future, more frames may be added and index may fail unexpectedly where name/ID is much less likely to change.

Comment: try using a wait... you may be seeing this error because it is still loading: "new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.locator));"

Comment: @JeffC yes. using id or name would be wiser if those attributes are more static.

Comment: thank you all for responding. I got the solution! @JeffC thank you for suggesting to use ID or name. I used ID and the only change I made in my code is instead of driver.switchTo().frame(iFrame_id) I used    driver.switchTo().frame(findElement(By.id(iFrame_id)));

Comment: @iamdanchiv thank you for making the post look professional !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make this work via @JeffC's  suggestions to use `id` or `name`. I used ID and the only change I made in my code is as follows:

Instead of:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(iFrame_id)
```

... I used:

```
 driver.switchTo().frame(findElement(By.id(iFrame_id)))
```

Thanks to everyone who helped!